# React-Native TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...this.state.feeds.map...')

Tags: react-native

I am trying to display news feed from url on my app screen. I have made a component for that (Parser) and have imported it in my master.js file.

I am using **axios** to get data from the urls.

I have written this code while i was learning from a tutorial, this code worked in the video but not working with me.

Upon compiling, the app shows error **TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...this.state.feeds.map...')**

I am running
Expo: 3.0.1
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.57.1
npm: 6.11.3

The code for component which fetches the data is:

```
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
        feeds: []
    }
}

componentWillMount(){
    axios.get('https://cointelegraph.com/rss')
      .then(response => this.setState({ feeds: response.data }));
}

renderFeeds = () => {
    return this.state.feeds.map(feed => <Text>{feed.title}</Text>);
}

render(){
    return (
        <View>
            {this.renderFeeds()}
        </View>
    );
}
```

The error being displayed is:
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3q0MN.jpg)

TIA

Comment: Are you sure `response.data` is an array? It could be a string which would throw this error.

Comment: I advise to use `componentDidMount` for your API call.

Comment: Response from `https://cointelegraph.com/rss` is in `XML` format.

Answer (score 0):

The map function only exists on arrays.
Make sure response.data is an array.